# How to mention MYSQLDialect for hibernate 5.4.17 and MySQL 8.0?

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate 5.4.17 in the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file. I have the dialect property like this:

```xml
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
```

Is this fine to use or Should I change it to:

```xml
 <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</property>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of your hibernate dialect should be as closer as possible to your database version. But should not be higher than database version. So for your case the `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect` will be the best choice.

See also [this section](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#database-dialect) of the hibernate documentation for further details.

Comment: In the hibernate configuration file, some web applications   use "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"   as Driver class.  But  com.mysql.jdbc.Driver   is also the same or is it different ?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-api-changes.html): The name of the class that implements `java.sql.Driver` in MySQL Connector/J has changed from `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` to `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`. *The old class name has been deprecated*.

Answer (score 1):

For others stumbling upon this answer: This has changed for newer versions of Hibernate. From the [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/Dialect.html):

> Since Hibernate 6, a single subclass of Dialect represents all releases of a given product-specific SQL dialect. The version of the database is exposed at runtime via the DialectResolutionInfo passed to the constructor, and by the getVersion() property.
>
> Programs using Hibernate should migrate away from the use of versioned dialect classes like, for example, MySQL8Dialect. These classes are now deprecated and will be removed in a future release.

So you should use `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect` if you have hibernate 6 or above.